# Block Inserts Compatibility

Tags: guitar

I'm fixing a guitar and the owner lost his Floyd Rose saddle inserts. The guitar has a Floyd Rose Special system. Are the Floyd Rose Schaller saddle inserts compatible with Floyd Rose special? Or should i search specific saddle inserts for Floyd Rose special?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

An entire saddle set for the Floyd Rose Special is about the same cost as a decent set of strings (search at https://floydrose.com). I'd just replace the whole set and keep it genuine.